# Вернуть select из ф-ии

Tags: mysql

Объясните, пожалуйста, как вернуть результат вложенного запроса(список) не используя промежуточных переменных

```
delimiter |
CREATE FUNCTION NumberAdress2()

BEGIN
    RETURN select pnumber,
    (select adress from FamilyBirthAdress fba where pp.id = fba.id)
 from PersonPhone pp;
END |
```

> Ошибка:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN     RETURN select pnumber,     (select adress from FamilyBirthAdress fba w' at line 2

Comment: Сделайте процедуру, а не функцию и уберите слово return. MySQL сам вернет вам выборку

Comment: В задании через ф-ю надо вернуть

Comment: Но MySQL так не умеет

Comment: Представление тоже нельзя вернуть из ф-ии?

Comment: Нет. Функция возвращает только скалярную величину

Comment: Возможно, требуется просто собрать все в строку и затем уже вернуть ее из функции?